# css3 -webkit-transform

Tags: css, webkit-transform

when I use

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
-webkit-transform: rotateY(-50deg) translateZ(1px) scale(0.8);
```

for a element, find only half of this element can click,who can help me

Comment: Don't understand the question...

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a `z-index` issue.

Try to apply `z-index:10` to the element